# Relation between Positive (semi)definiteness of Autocorrelation matrix and positivity of Power Spectral Density

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

For any given autocorrelation matrix i.e. Hermitian symmetric, Toeplitz, and positive (semi)definite, can it be shown that the power spectrum density obtained from the autocorrelation function corresponding to the autocorrelation matrix is positive.

In mathematical notation, given $\mathbf{R}\in\mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$ such that $ \mathbf{R}\geq 0$ and Toeplitz, is $S(f)\geq 0, \forall f$, where

\begin{equation}
S(f) = \sum\limits_{m=-(M-1)}^{M-1} r(m) e^{-j2\pi fm}
\end{equation}

and $ r(m) = [\mathbf{R}]_{l,l-m} $ for any $l$ (because of Toeplitz structure).

Comment: What do you want to ask? And what is your expected answer?

Comment: Initially, I wanted to know if an Hermitian symmetric positive definite Toeplitz matrix, whose elements correspond to the samples of an arbitrary autocorrelation function, resulted in a positive power spectrum (PSD)?
Intuitively, the answer should be that the PSD is positive. But after testing on some matrices in MATLAB, I found that the PSD need not always be positive. I don't understand why and now, I am looking for an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: @Karthik Upadhya PSD is always nonnegative. There is maybe a mistake in your calculations. Can you give more details on how you find it negative?